# dplyr and dcast over database connection

Tags: r, dplyr

I connect to postgresql tbl and name it def0113. When I need to make a 
table in the wide format with dcast I figured out that the only way is explicit data.frame in the code.

```
#Connection to postgresql tbl. This table has three columns (variables)
#provre: state, grupedad: age group and sexo: sex 
#and every row is a dead case. 
db=src_postgres(dbname = 'mdb', user = "postgres",
password ="mypass", options="-c search_path=mortalidad")
def0113 = tbl(db, 'def0113') 

def0113 %>%
filter(grupedad%like%'M%', provre == '30') %>%
data.frame() %>%
dcast(provre+sexo~grupedad)
```

The result is:

```
Using sitlabor as value column: use value.var to override.
Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length
    provre sexo   M1  M2  M3
1     30    1  89   39   47
2     30    2   31   20   47
3     30    3    5   1   2
4     30    9    6   0   0
```

There is a way to do this without %>% data.frame()?

I also tried:

```
def0113 %>%
filter(grupedad%like%'M%', provre == '30') %>%
group_by(grupedad, provre, sexo) %>%
summarise(casos = n()) %>%
spread(grupedad, casos)
```

but I got this

```
Error in UseMethod("spread_") : 
no applicable method for 'spread_' applied to an object of class
"c('tbl_postgres', 'tbl_sql', 'tbl')"
```

Then I tried:

```
def0113 %>%
filter(grupedad%like%'M%', provre == '30') %>%
group_by(grupedad, provre, sexo) %>%
summarise(casos = n()) %>%
data.frame() %>%
spread(grupedad, casos)
```

And I got my expected result:

```
  provre sexo   M1  M2  M3
1     30    1 89 39 47
2     30    2  31 20 47
3     30    3    5   1   2
4     30    9    6  NA  NA
```

Why I need to create a data.frame. def0113 is not a data.frame?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `dcast` is coming from `reshape2`, right? Consider using the `spread()` function from `tidyr` which has a special method for `tbl_df` objects which is what i'm guessing is being returned by `filter()` (but your example isn't reproducible so i don't know for sure)

Comment: Please provide an example which reproduces the error, otherwise it will be guesswork.

Comment: Did someone find a solution for this? I am stuck with the same issue. I dont want to transform to a dataframe because it takes a longer time.